# Collecting recursive function responses in an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, binary-search-tree

My question in short is: How can I collect the intermediate responses/output of a recursive function/method in an array and later print that array somewhere else?

Suppose I have a Node class:

```
class Node {
  constructor (data) {
    this.data = data
    this.left = null
    this.right = null
    this.parent = null
  }
}
```

And a BST class

```
class BST {
  constructor () {
    this.root = null
    this.nodeCount = 0
  }
  insert (data) {
    const node = new Node(data)
    this.nodeCount++
    if (this.root == null) {
      this.root = node
    } else {
      this.insertNode(this.root, node)
    }
    return this.search(data)
  }
  insertNode (node, newNode) {
    if (newNode.data < node.data) {
      if (node.left === null) {
        newNode.parent = node
        node.left = newNode
      } else {
        this.insertNode(node.left, newNode)
      }
    } else {
      if (node.right === null) {
        newNode.parent = node
        node.right = newNode
      } else {
        this.insertNode(node.right, newNode)
      }
    }
  }
  inOrder (node) {
    if (node !== null) {
      this.inOrder(node.left)
      console.log(node.data)
      this.inOrder(node.right)
    }
  }
  createTree (bst, arr = []) {
    for (let item of arr) {
      bst.insert(item)
    }
    return bst
  }
}
```

Now that I have those two classes, I can create a binary tree:

```
const bst = new BST()
const tree = bst.createTree(bst, [15, 25, 10, 7, 22, 17, 13, 5, 9, 27])
const root = tree.getRootNode()
```

And then traverse:

```
console.log('Traversing tree (InOrder): ')
bst.inOrder(root)
```

What I want to do is while traversing I want to push all the values in an array rather than printing it. As result of running *bst.inOrder()*, I will get an array with all the elements in the tree. How can I do that? Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Your current code results in `Uncaught TypeError: this.search is not a function @ JS line 22`. Have you made an attempt to collect the values into an array yourself? Please post what you've tried in that regard

Comment: You can replace `console.log` and the line below it with `return [node.data].concat(this.inOrder(node.right) || [])`

Comment: @blex, thanks for your answer but it's not working properly. For example, if I create a tree with the items like : [15, 25, 10, 7, 22, 17, 13, 5, 9, 27] then I get the response [15, 25, 27] which means that the result array has items of only right side of the tree from root element.

Comment: @CertainPerformance you can delete that line. I just added this method to verify that inserted item is available or not and If I need to post what I have tried the question will be much bigger to read which I feel unnecessary as they are not working. But I can give you one hint of what I have tried. In the BST class I created a class array variable and tried to push in it while traversing. But when I try to access that array later I find undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have found a way to solve this issue. Following is the method which does In Order Depth First Traverse that gives me a sorted array in response:

```js
traverse(cb) {
  function dfs(node) {
    if (node === null) return
    dfs(node.left)
    cb(node)
    dfs(node.right)
    return node
   }
   dfs(this.root)
   return this
}
```

This method should be in BST class. In the main function after inserting items into the tree (code written in the question), I have to write following code:

```js
const inOrderData = []
bst.traverse(function (node) {
  inOrderData.push(node.data)
})
console.log("Tree data: ", inOrderData)
```

So basically what I have done is I have sent a callback function to traverse method as a parameter and that callback function accepts a node as a parameter. Then inside the main function I just push the data of node into an array.